# Using Cypress, getting "warn mocha-intellij: cannot load "./lib/utils". Caused by Error: Cannot find module 'mocha'"

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js, cypress

Just wondering if anyone has seen this error or something similar?

Using:

- Cypress 8.3.0 Cypress
- Harvester plugin 1.1.0
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 Ultimate
- Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159

I am creating some tests using Cypress. Some of the tests involve tables, making sure that the tables can be sorted (ascending and descending) properly by different columns. I use Cypress-Harvester to "scrape" the table and assert that the sorting is correct.

Some of the column checks work fine. But for some reason, checking other columns is throwing an error, ending the test. This is an example of the Cypress/Cypress-Harvester code which works just fine:

```
                //Sorting by Task asc
                cy.task('log', '  Testing sorted by TASK # ascending...')
                cy.getByID('taskIdHeader').click()

                cy.get('#dataTable')
                    .should('have.length.above', 0)
                    .scrapeTable()
                    .then((table) => {
                            expect(table.columnLabels).to.deep.eq([
                                'Task ↓',
                                'Name',
                                'Date Received',
                                'Type',
                                'Group'])

                            expect(table.isPropertySorted(['task'], ['asc'])).to.be.true
                        }
                    )
```

This is an example of the Cypress/Cypress-Harvester code which fails the assertion:

```
                //Sorting by NAME asc
                cy.task('log', '  Testing sorted by NAME ascending...')
                cy.getByID('unitNameNumberHeader').click()

                cy.get('#dataTable')
                    .should('have.length.above', 0)
                    .scrapeTable()
                    .then((table) => {
                            expect(table.columnLabels).to.deep.eq([
                                'Task #',
                                'Name ↓',
                                'Date Received',
                                'Type',
                                'Group'])

                            expect(table.isPropertySorted(['name'], ['asc'])).to.be.true
                        }
                    )
```

This is the error:

```
warn mocha-intellij: cannot load "./lib/utils". Caused by  Error: Cannot find module 'mocha'

Require stack:
C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypressIntellijUtil.js
C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypressIntellijTree.js
C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\index.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\reporter.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\project-base.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\project_static.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\modes\run.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\modes\run-e2e.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\modes\index.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\cypress.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\index.js
C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:15)
    at Function.n._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:257:1128)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:94:19)
    at findMochaInnerDependency (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypressIntellijUtil.js:213:35)
    at requireMochaModule (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypressIntellijUtil.js:184:29)
    at Object.requireMochaUtils (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypressIntellijUtil.js:278:24)
    at Object.stringify (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypress-intellij-stringifier.js:10:29)
    at finishTestNode (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\index.js:211:35)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\index.js:383:7)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (C:\dev\TestApp\node_modules\cypress-intellij-reporter\lib\cypressIntellijUtil.js:129:17)
    at Runner.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Reporter.emit (C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\reporter.js:333:46)
    at ProjectBase.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\project-base.js:449:34)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:16)
    at Object.onMocha (C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\project-base.js:442:51)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\socket-base.js:213:40)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\socket\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)
    at C:\Users\kodriscoll\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\socket\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:428:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\dev\\TestApp\\node_modules\\cypress-intellij-reporter\\lib\\cypressIntellijUtil.js',
    'C:\\dev\\TestApp\\node_modules\\cypress-intellij-reporter\\lib\\cypressIntellijTree.js',
    'C:\\dev\\TestApp\\node_modules\\cypress-intellij-reporter\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\reporter.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\project-base.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\project_static.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\modes\\run.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\modes\\run-e2e.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\modes\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\lib\\cypress.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\server\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kodriscoll\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\8.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\index.js',
    undefined
  ]
}

AssertionError: expected false to be true
Expected :"true"
Actual   :false
```

Thanks!

The test also fails using the Cypress GUI Test Runner, but no mention of the mocha file:

[Error as shown the Cypress GUI Test Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1epR.png)

The test also fails if I exit IntelliJ and run it from a Windows CMD line. Again, no detailed error is thrown:

[Error as shown at a Windows CMD line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPtRG.png)

Comment: The stack trace you provided shows that the current problem is about mocha module resolving. Do you have mocha installed in you project or globally?

Also, do you run the test directly from IDE using the intellij-cypress plugin, right? You can run it from console and check if it fails. This way the reporter will not be used and so it will not hide the real problem.

Comment: I have not installed installed mocha as a separate module. The only mocha installed is what is bundled with cypress and/or cypress plugins.
The test also fails when I run it with the cypress test runner. And it also fails if I close IntelliJ and run the test from a Windows cmd box. However, neither of these to produce any errors regarding mocha. I ran the test again at the CLI with set DEBUG=cypress:* but I'm not able/qualified to see what it may be having an issue with.

Comment: As I said before, I think it shows the real problem when you run it  from command line (without the reporter).
So it seems you have 2 problems at the moment:
1. Some real problem in your code
2. A problem at reporting any problem via mocha reporter which hides the real problem.

They are independent and have to be solved separately. 
You can create an issue against the second one here:
https://github.com/mbolotov/cypress-intellij-reporter

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into your #1 (I believe now the real issue is with the cypress-harvester plugin). Regarding your #2, I have created the following issue for cypress-intellij-reporter:

    https://github.com/mbolotov/cypress-intellij-reporter/issues/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the above test within IntelliJ, the cypress-intellij-reporter is generating the above error message upon test failure which is preventing the true test failure error(s) from surfacing. When I exit IntelliJ and run the above test at a Windows CMD line, it removes cypress-intellij-reporter from the equation. The test still fails but for other reasons in the test code. I have opened the following issue against cypress-intellij-reporter:

https://github.com/mbolotov/cypress-intellij-reporter/issues/3